# Customize checkresiduals() function in R with a `ggtheme` package

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am writing a report in RMarkdown. Using a classic `theme_economist()` for visualizations.

All my plots have the same style. For example

[image]

But there is one function, [`checkresiduals()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.12/topics/checkresiduals), which is not a part of the `tidyverse` family and I cannot customize it with `theme_economist()`.

As a result, it is the only plot without a theme, which annoys a bit my perfectionism.

Any chance to customize it?

[image]

There are other ways to plot residuals with `ggplot2()`, but I like that function. Maybe somebody knows how to customize it? I appreciate your tips!

**A REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE**

```
# Packages
library(tidyverse)
library(forecast)
library(ggthemes)

# Data
data(mtcars)

# Create a plot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, hp)) + 
   geom_point(color = "red", size = 3) + 
   labs(title = "I love mtcars",
        subtitle = "Do you love mtcars?",
        x = "disp",
        y = "hp") +
   theme_economist()

# Fit a model
mtcars_model <- lm(disp ~ hp, data = mtcars)

# Check residuals
checkresiduals(mtcars_model, color = "red")
```

Output

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like that function makes it easy to customize the ggplots it returns, but since you are just setting a theme, you can set a global theme.

```
theme_set(theme_economist())
```

which will change the theme for all subsequent plots in your session. Alternatively you could write a wrapper to change the theme, draw the plot, then change it back. For example

```
with_theme_economist <- function(expr) {
  orig <- theme_get()
  theme_set(theme_economist())
  force(expr)
  theme_set(orig)
}

with_theme_economist(checkresiduals(mtcars_model, color = "red"))
```

Comment: Damn, that easy with a `theme_set`! I was thinking I need to wrap it somehow. Thank you, good sir!